# How to modify simple-type variables defined in a C++ dll in a C# code?

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I am sorry if this is a simple question. I have found extensive documentation on how to call functions and how to see structures, but I could not find any reference on how to modify single-types variables defined in the dll.

As an example, single types variables are defined in the c++ dll as

```
extern long N;

extern char M[MAXM];
```

My specific question in this case is: does anybody know how to retreive and modify these variables in a C# code?

Comment: modify how? `extern char M[MAXM]` to `???`

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. I want to see and modify the values (not the type) of N and M in a C# code.

Answer (score 0):

In a separate communication, he recommended me to build functions in the C++ dll that can get and set the values for the variables of interest. There may not be a simpler approach here. :-(